# Which processor is better for multitasking and processing - GeForce940MX (4GB) or Geforce MX150 (2GB)?

Tags: memory, graphics-card, cpu, performance, nvidia-graphics-card

I'm really confused between 2 laptops. I know **MX150** is newer but it has only **2**GB RAM. **940MX** is old but has **4**GB RAM. Both laptops have almost same configurations *(i7 8th generation, 8GB RAM)* but I'm only concerned about GPU.

My primary task is graphic design *(Adobe products)*. Other things I want to do is play games and little video editing *(After effects and Premiere Pro)*.

So, which processor is better in terms of performance keeping in mind VRAM?

Answer (score 1):

The MX150 is significantly faster (circa 25%) according to [these](https://gpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Nvidia-MX150-0-vs-Nvidia-940MX/m332822vsm88506) benchmarks - although this will depend on if the GeForce940 has DDR3 or DDR5 memory.  It is also more energy efficient then the 940MX.   (Indeed it is 18 months newer, and the replacement for the 940MX)

The RAM would appear to be more important for 4k editing or heavy multi-screen use, so the answer really depends on the resolution you intend to drive your screen at.  For gaming - At lower resolution, 2 gigs should be adequate but as you get past 720p that advantage will start disappearing - depending on the complexity of the textures and your particular game - however I suspect that neither GPU will be able to handle high detail gaming particularly well.

I don't think most graphic design will care too much about the memory of the card, so for that purpose the MX150 is probably better - and all else being equal I would get the newer MX150 over the 940MX.

Comment: 940MX has DDR5 memory. Is there anything else to say/edit now?

Comment: Further, this doubt came when I read on Quora that 940MX is not powerful to handle/use 4GB memory. 4GB is a waste. Is that true? How can I know more about that?